# How do you go to precise coordinates using Google Maps API search box?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, geocoding

I'm trying to figure out how to move to exact coordinates using the Google Maps Javascript API places search box.

Using the example from the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox), I added a couple of alerts:

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      alert(place.geometry.location.lat());
      alert(place.geometry.location.lng());
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

If I enter, for example, **47, -121** I get taken to **46.9905925, -120.9854728** - some distance from where I want to be. Google Maps and Google Earth both take me to the correct location.

How can I make the Places search box work correctly? I've tried using DMS, DMM and DD formats, but they don't work reliably. For example, **47°30' N, 121°30' W** works, but **47°0' N, 121°0' W** doesn't (this doesn't go anywhere), nor does **47.0000, -121.000**

Comment: If you know the coordinates you want to go to, why are you using the search box?  Just go to them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3: Turning user input coordinates to latlng?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368928/google-maps-api-v3-turning-user-input-coordinates-to-latlng)

Comment: @geocodezip I want my users to be able to navigate to coordinates the way they can using Google Maps or Google Earth

Comment: That functionality is not part of the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Search Box (see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox)).  If you want that, you will need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for whatever reason, Google's default search box implementation only patchily supports coordinate input. As suggested in the comments it is necessary to roll-your-own solution.

Using [this parsing code](https://github.com/gmaclennan/parse-dms) you can respond when no places are found thus:

```js
var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
if (places.length == 0) {
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var result = parseDMS(input.value);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(result.lat, result.lon);
  bounds.extend(latlng);
  // Create a marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: 'Coordinates',
    position: latlng
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  return;
}
```